# JSON from WCF service to android object

Tags: android, json, gson

I have REST C# WCF web service that returns JSON.

```
{
   "GetProductResult": 
    {
    "title": "Fishing stick",
    "description": "Brand new"
    }
}
```

Then I try to "parse" it using GSON (I'm using android studio) with this

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonOutput = "{\"GetProductResults\":{\"name\":\"Fishing stick\",\"description\":\"Brand new\"}}";
    MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(jsonOutput, MyObject.class);
    Log.d("OBJ",obj.title);
```

But the problem I gotis that MyObject is empty. If I change JSON string to

```
 {
    "title": "Fishing stick",
    "description": "Brand new"
}
```

it works. The only difference here is that I removed "GetProductResult" array and MyObject is populated with "title" and "description".

Here's MyObject class:

```
public class MyObject {
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: My guess is that the error is happening on `MyObject` class. Maybe you are missing something there? Post your code?

Comment: Edit your MyObject class so that it matches the structure of your JSON?

Comment: I think that It does. It has title and description properties. What else should MyObject contain?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to figured it out. The issues lies in WCF web service.

Method need to have

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```

So final result is something like this

```
[OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
      UriTemplate = "getProduct")]
     List<Product> getProduct();
```